# Embbed outlook mails into word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, outlook, automation

Is there a way to embbed outlook mailitems into word document programatically from a Outlook Mailitem List.??

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
Word.Application wdApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing);

foreach(Outlook.MailItem olMail in mailAttachments)
{
   //Paste/embbed this olMail into the word document
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya Finally i found an effective solution

I used the [InlineShapes.AddOLEObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addoleobject(v=office.15).aspx) method

My solution:

```
static void creatDocument(List<Outlook.MailItems> mailAttachments)
{

 string userprofile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);  

 object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
 object start=0;
 object end =0;
 object classType ="{00020D0B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}";     
 object fileName;
 object linkToFile = false;
 object displayAsIcon = true;
 object iconFileName = Path.Combine(userprofile,"Pictures\MailIcon.ico");
 object iconIndex =0;
 object iconLabel;
 object range;

 Word.Application wdApp=new Word.Application();
 Word.Document wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

 Range rng = wdDoc.Range(ref start,ref missing);

 foreach(outlook.MailItem olMail in mailAttachments)
 {
   olMail.SaveAs(Path.Combine(userprofile,"Documents\TemperoraySave") + CleanFileName(olMail.Subject) + ".msg" ,Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMsg);
   fileName = Path.Combine(userprofile,"Documents\TemperoraySave") + CleanFileName(olMail.Subject) + ".msg"
   iconLabel = CleanFIleName(olMail.Subject) + ".msg";

   rng = wdDoc.Content;
   rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
   range = rng;

   wdDoc.InLineShapes.AddOLEObject(ref classType,ref fileName,ref linkToFile,ref displayAsIcon,ref iconFIleName,ref iconIndex,ref iconLabel,ref range);

   var mailRanger = wdDoc.Paragraphs.Add();
   mailRanger.Format.SpaceAfter =10f;
 }

}
 private static string CleanFileName(string fileName)
    {
        return Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(fileName, (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The Word object model doesn't provide anything for that. Instead, you may consider using the CustomDocumentProperties[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195603(v=office.15).aspx) collection for storing your custom data. For example, you may save the message as an .msg file and save the path to the file or the ID of the record in the database to a custom document property. After, when you need to open a message you can get the ID or path for retrieving the email message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed the source text of the emails, but you can copy the MailItem.HTMLBody or MailItem.Body (text) values and insert them into the Word document.